# Error member function on a non-object Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I had a problem in Symfon2, which is :

> Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/UserBO/src/BO/UserBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
>   line 88

Entity Form contains many entity docs,
my code is :

```
public function userAction()
{
    $data = array();
    $row = array();
    $extra = array();

    $results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("BOUserBundle:Form")->createQueryBuilder('q')->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
  //  var_dump($results); die;
    foreach ($results as $res){

        $row = array(
            'id' => $res->getId(),
            'name' => $res->getName(),
            'adresse' => $res->getAdresse()

        );

    $docs = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("BOUserBundle:Document")->find($res->getId());

    foreach ($docs as $doc)
    {
        $extra[] = array(
            'id'=> $doc->getId(),   **// line 88**
            'name doc'=> $doc->getName(),
            'path' => $doc->getPath()
        );
    }
    $row = array_merge($row, array('docs'=>$extra));
    }
    // var_dump($data); die;
    $data[] = $row;

   return new JsonResponse($data);
    //return $this->render('BOUserBundle:Default:user.html.twig', array('data' => $data));
}
```

thank's

**EDIT :**

> $results =
>   $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("BOUserBundle:Form")->createQueryBuilder('q')->getQuery()->getResult();
>         var_dump($results); die;

Using **getResult** it blocks the navigator (Mozilla), and **getArrayResult()** it's not,so what's the problem ?

Comment: `$doc` isn't an object. `var_dump` it and see what it really is.

Comment: Are you sure the line 88 is were you marked it ? Normally you can't do $res->getId() with getArrayResult .

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about line 88, when I did **getResult** it crashs my navigator, any idea ?

Comment: check php errors for the crashing cause

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache resolve my issue.
the command is :

```
php app/console cache:clear
```